# How can I get Mathematica to simplify my square root expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

$$\sqrt{r^2 e^{4 \gamma (r)-4 \psi (r)}}$$

If I set

```
var = r^2*E^(4 \[Gamma][r] - 4 \[Psi][r])

Simplify[Sqrt[var], var > 0]
```

I just get

$$\left| r\right|  \sqrt{e^{4 \gamma (r)-4 \psi (r)}}$$

How to tell Mathematica to perform the full square root calculation?

$$r e^{2 \gamma (r)-2 \psi (r)}$$

Comment: ya r has been taken...simple mathematical rule
`Simplify[Sqrt[(r^2)*E^(4 \[Gamma][r] - 4 \[Psi][r])]]//PowerExpand`

Comment: Thank you! Why does it work?

Comment: Your concern is code snippet or 'r' ?

Comment: My concern is to get rid of the square root.

Comment: I think your question is unclear to us, you haven't mentioned getting rid of it. Please be more precise.

Comment: Sorry. I'll clarify. Your code just do the business. I wanted to know why we have to use PowerExpand to achieve the result.

Comment: It's mathematica's way to expand an expression based on its power which in this case is 1/2.You can refer docs for further details on it.

Comment: Use e.g. `Simplify[ Sqrt[var], 
 r \[Element] Reals && (4 \[Gamma][r] - 4 \[Psi][r]) \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: Hmm, even better. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I think this question already has an answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/)

Comment: Looking there, now I see why PowerExpand works: "An additional note: PowerExpand assumes that the variables are real and positive. – rcollyer Sep 28 '12 at 2:55". Artes answer directly solves the problem.

Comment: Feel free to delete this question if you think it is a duplicate though.